function gives equal value before and after changing a variable
The output comes true. Since after first function call to f() we changed a by adding h, it still shows them equal. Can anyone explain why?


let g = 0;
let a = {};
let f = () => {
  if (g === 1) {
    a.h = 2;
  };
  g++;
  return a;
}
console.log(f() === f());




You are comparing the object a not the content of the object. BTW there is only one object referenced by a

Simply because they both return the same object reference a.
First, f() is called the first time:

g is 0, so a.h = 2 does not execute.
g increments to 1.
Returns the object a (still {} at this point).

Then, f() is called the second time:

Now g is 1, so a.h = 2 executes and modifies a to { h: 2 }.
g increments to 2.
Returns the modified object a (now { h: 2 }).

Even though the internal state of changes between calls, both calls return the same memory reference to a

can you just tell me what return a returns the memory location or the value at that memory?what i mean is what the compiler is putting in place of f( ) in f( )=f( );

@Ujjawal it returns the object. In JavaScript we don’t concern ourselves with memory locations.

@KevinB but both objects are different. One is { } and other is {h:2} in f( ) in f( )=f( ). So how are they equal

@Ujjawal that's the thing, they aren't different. the a variable holds a single object. changing the object doesn't assign a new object to the a variable.

@Ujjawal refer this answer to get more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/25921504/2427065

@Ujjawal, Imagine that a is just a pointer (reference) to an object which exists in memory, and whenever using/editing a it will reflect on the same object.

@Mina can you tell me what code replaces with  f( ) in f( )===f( ) . is it { } , a, memory location or something else?

@Ujjawal It will be as if a === a where a = { h: 2 }, but because they both have the same reference they are equal, for example, let's say let a = { h: 2 } ( a here a reference to an object equal to { h: 2 }), and let b = { h: 2 } ( b here a reference to an object equal to { h: 2 } but different than a), so b not equal to a, but if you make b = a, they both reference to the object in the memory.

@Ujjawal, If you still don't understand, I suggest watching this video to have a full understanding on what is the difference between reference and value.
